# Adding a 4th variable to a 3D plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mayavi, 4d

I have 3 different parameters X,Y and Z over a range of values, and for each combination of these a certain value of V. To make it clearer, the data would look something like this.

```
X  Y  Z  V
1  1  2  10
1  2  3  15
etc...
```

I'd like to visualize the data with a surface/contour plot, using V as a colour to see its value at that point, but I do not see how to add my custom colouring scheme into the mix using Python. Any idea on how to do this (or is this visualization outright silly)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A 3D scatter plot seems appriopriate, e.g. http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html .

Comment: Does your xy-data make a rectilinear grid or are the coordinates x and y pretty much randomly distributed?

Comment: Yes, X, Y and Z are regularly distributed.

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib allows one to pass the facecolors as an argument to e.g.
[`ax.plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface).

That would imply then that you would have to perform 2D interpolation on your
current array of colors, because you currently only have the colors in the
corners of the rectangular faces (you did mention that you have a rectilinear
grid).

You could use
[`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)
for that, but as you see from the documentation, it is suggested to use
[`scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html).

To give you a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
y,x = np.mgrid[1:10:10j, 1:10:10j] # returns 2D arrays
# You have 1D arrays that would make a rectangular grid if properly reshaped.
y,x = y.ravel(), x.ravel()  # so let's convert to 1D arrays
z = x*(x-y)
colors = np.cos(x**2) - np.sin(y)**2
```

Now I have a similar dataset as you (one-dimensional arrays for `x, y, z` and
`colors`). Remark that the colors are defined for
each point (x,y). But when you want to plot with `plot_surface`, you'll
generate rectangular patches, of which the corners are given by those points.

So, on to interpolation then:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
# from scipy.interpolate import interp2d # could 've used this too, but docs suggest the faster RectBivariateSpline

# Define the points at the centers of the faces:
y_coords, x_coords = np.unique(y), np.unique(x)
y_centers, x_centers = [ arr[:-1] + np.diff(arr)/2 for arr in (y_coords, x_coords)]

# Convert back to a 2D grid, required for plot_surface:
Y = y.reshape(y_coords.size, -1)
X = x.reshape(-1, x_coords.size)
Z = z.reshape(X.shape)
C = colors.reshape(X.shape)
#Normalize the colors to fit in the range 0-1, ready for using in the colormap:
C -= C.min()
C /= C.max()

interp_func = RectBivariateSpline(x_coords, y_coords, C.T, kx=1, ky=1) # the kx, ky define the order of interpolation. Keep it simple, use linear interpolation.
```

In this last step, you could also have used `interp2d` (with `kind='linear'`
replacing the `kx=1, ky=1`). But since the docs suggest to use the faster
`RectBivariateSpline`...

Now you're ready to plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.cm as cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
r = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,
    facecolors=cm.hot(interp_func(x_centers, y_centers).T),
    rstride=1,  cstride=1) # only added because of this very limited dataset
```

[image: output]

As you can see, the colors on the faces have nothing to do anymore with the height of the dataset.

Note that you could have thought simply passing the 2D array C to `facecolors` would work, and matplotlib would not have complained. However, the result isn't accurate then, because matplotlib will use only a subset of C for the facecolors (it seems to ignore the last column and last row of C). It is equivalent to using only the color defined by one coordinate (e.g. the top-left) over the entire patch.

An easier method would have been to let matplotlib do the interpolation and obtain the facecolors and then pass those in to the real plot:

```
r = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,C, cmap='hot') # first plot the 2nd dataset, i.e. the colors
fc = r.get_facecolors()
ax.clear()
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=fc)
```

However, that won't work in releases <= 1.4.1 due to [this recently submitted bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4067).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you plan on plotting this data. I like to plot graphs with `gnuplot`: it's easy, free and intuitive. To plot your example with `gnuplot` you'd have to print those line into a file (with only those four columns) and plot using a code like the following

```
 reset
 set terminal png
 set output "out.png"
 splot "file.txt" using 1:2:3:4 with lines palette
```

Assuming that you save your data into the file `file.txt`. `splot` stands for surface plot. Of course, this is a minimum example.

Alternatively you can use `matplotlib`, but that is not, in my opinion, as intuitive. Although it has the advantage of centering all the processing in python.